# Assign to a bash array variable indirectly, by dynamically constructed variable name

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, eval, indirection

Bash script to create multiple arrays from csv with unknown columns.

I am trying to write a script to compare two csv files with similar columns.  I need it to locate the matching column from the other csv and compare any differences.  The kicker is I would like the script to be dynamic to allow any number of columns to be entered and it still be able to function. I thought I had a good plan to solve this but turns out I'm running into syntax errors. Here is a sample of a csv I need to compare.

```
IP address, Notes,  Nmap-SSH,   Nmap-SMTP, Nmap-HTTP, Nmap-HTTPS,
10.0.0.1,   ,       open,       closed,     open,     open,
10.0.0.2,   ,       closed,     open,       closed,   closed,
```

When I read the csv file I was planning to look for "IF column == open; then; populate this column's array with the IP address"  This would have given me 4 lists in this scenario with the IPs that were listening on said port. I could then compare that to my security device configuration to make sure it was configured properly. Finally to the meat, here is what I thought would accomplish creating the arrays for me to search later. However I ran into a snag when I tried to use a variable inside an array name. Can my syntax be corrected or is there just a better way to do this sort of thing?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
# This script compares config_cleaned_<ip>.txt output against ext_web_env.csv and outputs the differences
#
#
# Read from ext_web_env.csv file and create Array
#
        FILENAME=./tmp/ext_web_env.csv
#
        index=0
#
        while read line
          do
# How many columns are in the .csv?
        varEnvCol=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print NF}')
            echo "columns = $varEnvCol"

# While loop to create array for each column

                while [ $varEnvCol != 2 ]
                  do
# Checks to see if port is open; if so then add IP address to array
                   varPortCon=$(echo $line | awk -F, -v i=$varEnvCol '{print $i}')
                        if [ $varPortCon = "open" ]
                          then
                                arr$varEnvCol[$index]="$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')"
# I get this error message "line29 : arr8[194]=10.0.0.194: command not found"
                        fi
           echo "arrEnv$varEnvCol is: ${arr$varEnvCol[@]}"
# Another error but not as important since I am using this to debug "line31: arr$varEnvCol is: ${arr$varEnvCol[@]}: bad substitution"
                   varEnvCol=$(($varEnvCol - 1))
                done
                index=$(($index + 1 ))
          done < $FILENAME
```

UPDATE

I also tried using the eval command since all the data will be populated by other scripts.

but am getting this error message:

./compare.sh: line 41: arr8[83]=10.0.0.83: command not found

Here is my new code for this example:

```
 if [[ $varPortCon = *'open'* ]]
   then
    eval arr\$varEnvCol[$index]=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')
 fi
```

Comment: you are already using awk in your script, why not just use it?

Comment: @technosaurus is there a way to use awk to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 15):

```sh
arr$varEnvCol[$index]="$(...)"
```

**doesn't work the way you expect it to** - you cannot assign to shell variables *indirectly* - via an expression that *expands* to the variable name - *this way*.

Your attempted workaround with `eval` is also flawed - see below.

---

### tl;dr

#### If you use bash 4.3 or above:

```
declare -n targetArray="arr$varEnvCol"
targetArray[index]=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')
```

#### bash 4.2 or earlier:

```
declare "arr$varEnvCol"[index]="$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')"
```

*Caveat*: This will work in your particular situation, but *may fail subtly in others*; read on for details, including a *more robust, but cumbersome alternative based on* `read`.

The `eval`-based solution mentioned by [@shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) in a since-deleted comment is problematic not only for security reasons (as they mentioned), but also because it can get quite tricky with respect to *quoting*; for completeness, here's the `eval`-based solution:

```
eval "arr$varEnvCol[index]"='$(echo $line | awk -F, '\''{print $1}'\'')'
```

See below for an explanation.

---

### Assign to a `bash` array variable *indirectly*:

#### `bash 4.3+`: use `declare -n` to effectively create an *alias* ('nameref') of another variable

This is by far the best option, if available:

```
declare -n targetArray="arr$varEnvCol"
targetArray[index]=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')
```

`declare -n` effectively allows you to **refer to a variable by another name** (whether that variable is an array or not), and the name to create an alias for can be the result of an expression (an expanded string), as demonstrated.

#### `bash 4.2-`: there are *several options*, each with *tradeoffs*

NOTE: With ***non-array* variables**, the best approach is to **use `printf -v`**. Since this question is about *array* variables, this approach is not discussed further.

- **[most robust, but cumbersome]: use `read`**:

```sh
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' "arr$varEnvCol"[index] <<<"$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')"
```

- `IFS=$'\n'` ensures that that leading and trailing whitespace in each input line is left intact.
- `-r` prevents interpretation of `\` chars. in the input.
- `-d ''` ensures that **ALL input is captured, even multi-line**.

  - Note, however, that any **trailing `\n` chars. are stripped**.
  - If you're **only interested in the *first* line of input, omit `-d ''`**
- `"arr$varEnvCol"[index]` expands to the variable - array element, in this case - to *assign* to; note that referring to variable `index` inside an array subscript does NOT need the `$` prefix, because subscripts are evaluated in *arithmetic* context, where the prefix is *optional*.
- `<<<` - a so-called *here-string* - sends its argument to `stdin`, where `read` takes its input from.
- **[simplest, but may break]: use `declare`**:

```sh
declare "arr$varEnvCol"[index]="$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')"
```

- (This is slightly counter-intuitive, in that `declare` is meant to *declare*, not *modify* a variable, but it works in bash 3.x and 4.x, with the constraints noted below.)
- Works fine OUTSIDE a FUNCTION - whether the array was explicitly declared with `declare` or not.
- ***Caveat*: INSIDE a function, only works with LOCAL variables** - you **cannot reference shell-global variables (variables declared outside the function) from inside a function that way**. Attempting to do so invariably creates a LOCAL variable ECLIPSING the shell-global variable.
- **[insecure and tricky]: use `eval`**:

```sh
eval "arr$varEnvCol[index]"='$(echo $line | awk -F, '\''{print $1}'\'')'
```

- **CAVEAT: Only use `eval` if you fully control the contents of the string being evaluated; `eval` will execute *any* command contained in a string, with potentially unwanted results.**
- Understanding what variable references/command substitutions get expanded when is nontrivial - the **safest approach is to *delay* expansion** so that they happen when `eval` executes rather than *immediate* expansion that happens when *arguments are passed to* `eval`.
- For a variable assignment statement to succeed, the RHS (right-hand side) must eventually evaluate to a *single* token - either unquoted *without* whitespace or *quoted* (optionally with whitespace).
- The above example uses *single* quotes to delay expansion; thus, the string passed mustn't contain single quotes directly and thus is *broken into multiple parts* with literal `'` chars. *spliced in* as `\'`.
- Also note that the LHS (left-hand side) of the assignment statement passed to `eval` must be a *double-quoted* string - using an unquoted string with selective quoting of `$` won't work, curiously:

  - OK: `eval "arr$varEnvCol[index]"=...`
  - FAILS: `eval arr\$varEnvCol[index]=...`