# Bash array indirection in a function

Tags: arrays, bash, reference

Below, I have the demonstration of, and the listing of, functions in bash (4.2.46) for array manipulation - push, pop, shift, unshift. You'll notice that even though I pass the name of the array into the functions and assign it to the variable `array_name`, the function only works with the hardcoded array `array`. This is because I've been wraking my brain, my fingers, and the internet to no avail trying to determine the magic indirect incantation notation that would allow me to use `array_name` instead, and be able to modify any array in these functions. Would anyone like to take a crack at it?

Thanks

**UPDATE**. This question was marked as as a duplicate. I used that question to solve my issue. **And** I repointed my shell to use Bash 4.3+.

Below now is the **SOLUTION** to my issue of using array variable indirection:

```
$ foo=

$ foo=()

$ echo '** foo array**' ; for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $i;done
** foo array**

$ apush foo "item 1"

$ echo '** foo array**' ; for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $i;done
** foo array**
item 1

$ apush foo "item 2"

$ echo '** foo array**' ; for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $i;done
** foo array**
item 1
item 2

$ apush foo "item 3"

$ echo '** foo array**' ; for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $i;done
** foo array**
item 1
item 2
item 3

$ aunshift foo "item 0"

$ echo '** foo array**' ; for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $i;done
** foo array**
item 0
item 1
item 2
item 3

$ apop foo
item 3

$ echo '** foo array**' ; for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $i;done
** foo array**
item 0
item 1
item 2

$ ashift foo
item 0

$ echo '** foo array**' ; for i in "${foo[@]}"; do echo $i;done
** foo array**
item 1
item 2

## push, pop, shift, unshift:
## http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/911/queue-and-stack-using-array/
## http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691121/bash-array-expansion-using-variable-indirection-expansion
## http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819839/assign-to-a-bash-array-variable-indirectly-by-dynamically-constructed-variable

##bash 4.3+: use declare -n to effectively create an alias ('nameref') of another variable

aclear ()
{
    declare -n array_alias="$1"
    array_alias=()
}

apush ()
{
    declare -n array_alias="$1"
    local item="$2"
    local count=${#array_alias[@]}
    ## index = 0 to count-1. Next element is [count]
    array_alias[$count]="$item"
}

alist ()
{
    local use_idx=0
    if [ "$1" = '--idx' ]
    then
        use_idx=1
        shift
    fi

    declare -n array_alias="$1"
    if [ "$use_idx" = 1 ]
    then
        for i in "${!array_alias[@]}"
        do
            printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${array_alias[$i]}"
        done
    else
        for i in "${array_alias[@]}"
        do
            echo $i
        done
    fi
}

apop ()
{
    declare -n array_alias="$1"
    local item=${array_alias[((${#array_alias[@]}-1))]}
    array_alias=("${array_alias[@]:0:$((${#array_alias[@]}-1))}")
    echo $item
}

ashift ()
{
    declare -n array_alias="$1"
    local item=${array_alias[0]}
    array_alias=("${array_alias[@]:1}")
    echo $item
}

aunshift ()
{
    declare -n array_alias="$1"
    local item="$2"
    local i
    local j
    for (( i = ${#array_alias[@]} ; i > 0 ; i-- ))
    do
        ((j=i-1))
        array_alias[$i]="${array_alias[$j]}"
    done
    array_alias[0]="$item"
}

adelval ()
{
    declare -n array_alias="$1"
    local item=$2
    local i
    for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#array_alias[@]} ; i++ ))
    do
        if [ "$item" = "${array_alias[$i]}" ]
        then
            break
        fi
    done
    adelidx $i
}

adelidx ()
{
    declare -n array_alias="$1"
    local idx=$2
    array_alias=("${array_alias[@]:0:$idx}" "${array_alias[@]:$(($idx + 1))}")
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen. If you use `array=`, it assigns to the variable named `array`. What does the `array_name` variable have to do with it?

Comment: None of your code uses the `!` indirection operator. But that can only be used when reading from a variable, it can't used to assign to a variable.

Comment: Yes, I know I am not using indirection, but I wanted to post working code. All that is left is to ADD the indirection. That's what I was hoping to get advice on - how to assign to an array using indirect notation.

Comment: I hope the duplicate question I linked to helps you.

Comment: You know, I found that, but it is for individual assignments and the code I had wasn't doing that. However, a second look at both leads me to believe I could probably just change my code to do individual assignments. I will have to do some more assigning around which might make the code a little more inefficient. However, it should be much safer for assignments that contain spaces in them, Thank you for your help. When complete, I will post a solution for reference.